# How to execute jar maven project with Sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, maven

I compile a jar with maven, and when I try to execute this jar with the commande line "java -jar myProject.jar" it's work. However, if I double click on the jar, an popup error appears. And if I remove the Sqlite part of my code, it's work when I double click.

The Sqlite part I have removed :

```
public ArrayList<Enquete> findAll() {
    Enquete eleve = new Enquete();   
    ArrayList<Enquete> listeEleve = new ArrayList<Enquete();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM eleve";
    try {
        ResultSet rs = this.connect.getInstance().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
            listeEleve.add(new Enquete(
                    rs.getInt("id"),
                    rs.getString("nom")
                    ));         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listeEleve;
}
```

Comment: What is the popup error?

Comment: Impossible to launch the JAR java file "my-project.jar" Research in the prompt to see errors messages. And there is no error in the prompt.

Comment: This may be a (class)path issue. Is the SQLite driver contained in your .jar file?